# google closure library sanitizer.sanitize removes my id on dom elements

Tags: javascript, dom, google-closure-library

I am dynamically updating tabs with content using **goog.dom.safeHtmlToNode**

since the newer release of the google closure library removed the dom fragment method: **goog.dom.htmlToDocumentFragment(htmlString)**.

The sanitizer removes my "id=xyz" from the dom elements. For example:

```
'<input type="email" id="openid" name="openid" size="20" style="font-size: 18px" />'
```

becomes

```
'<input type="email" size="20" style="font-size: 18px;" />'
```

I was using the id to get the content the user input from these elements.  **How do I tell the sanitizer to NOT remove these attributes?**  I have tried the following code without success:

```
var sanitizer =
new goog.html.sanitizer.HtmlSanitizer.Builder()
.withCustomNetworkRequestUrlPolicy(goog.html.SafeUrl.sanitize)
.allowCssStyles()
.allowFormTag()
.addOriginalTagNames()  
.allowDataAttributes([ "data-id","data-name" ]) //data-* attributes are inert as per HTML5 specs
.build();

goog.dom.safeHtmlToNode( sanitizer.sanitize (htmlString) );
```

I have also tried renaming my "id" to "data-id", the string is still removed from the sanitized output.

```
Thank you in advance for your help on this matter.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This changes the token policy to allow all instead of allowing none.  The token policy is used for the ID and CLASS attributes, so this should allow you to keep your ID attribute.

```
.withCustomTokenPolicy(goog.functions.identity)
```

Comment: Thank you.  Setting the policy did the trick.  Where could I find additional documentation on the google closure library, i.e. tutorials, examples (yes I know about the demos that come with it).    I usually use the test programs to figure out how to call functions.  It would sure be nice to have more information!  Thank you in any case!  It now works!

Answer (score 0):

Here is your example as a test case via the [online closure compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home#code%3D%252F%252F%2520%253D%253DClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540compilation_level%2520ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540output_file_name%2520default.js%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540use_closure_library%2520true%250A%252F%252F%2520%253D%253D%252FClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%250Agoog.module('example')%253B%250A%250Avar%2520Builder%2520%253D%2520goog.require('goog.html.sanitizer.HtmlSanitizer.Builder')%253B%250Avar%2520SafeUrl%2520%253D%2520goog.require('goog.html.SafeUrl')%253B%250A%250A%252F%252F%2520ADD%2520YOUR%2520CODE%2520HERE%250Avar%2520sanitizer%2520%253D%250Anew%2520Builder()%250A.withCustomNetworkRequestUrlPolicy(SafeUrl.sanitize)%250A.allowCssStyles()%250A.allowFormTag()%250A.addOriginalTagNames()%250A.allowDataAttributes(%255B%2520%2522id%2522%252C%2520%2522data-id%2522%2520%255D)%250A.build()%253B%250A%250Avar%2520output%2520%253D%2520sanitizer.sanitize(%250A%2520%2520'%253Cinput%2520id%253D%2522id-is-here%2522%2520data-id%253D%2522data-id-is-here-also%2522%2520size%253D%252220%2522%2520%252F%253E'%2520)%253B%250Aconsole.log(output)%253B%250A)

I just added "id" and "data-id" as a value in the `.allowDataAttributes([ "id","data-id" ])`.

If you compile the example in "Advanced mode" and paste the result in a console you will see that the "id" and "data-id" are there.

Comment: I got an assert error at run-time.  I looked at the code and the prefix "data-" is required for this function.   Thank you though.... every hint helps!